# How to position images on the same line as an h1 element in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am completely stuck trying to get a left chevron and a right chevron to display on either side of a date in an `h1` tag. I want a user to be able to click on either chevron to move forward or backward one day. However, no matter what combination of `div` or `img` classes and `position, float, display` it still looks like the screenshot attached, even though I've made sure the document is updating.

How can I modify the HTML/CSS so the chevrons are placed on the same line as the date?

```
<div class= "dater">
  <div class="chevron-left">
     <img src="glyphicons-225-chevron-left.png"/>
  </div>  
  <h2><%= @todie %></h2>
  <div class="chevron-right">
     <img src="glyphicons-224-chevron-right.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

#### EDIT: My solution based on Rob's answer.

```
.chevron-right img {
  float: right;

}

.chevron-left img {
 float: left;

}

.dater {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.dater h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: post your css please, anyways, float the `.chevron-left` and `h2` to the left

Comment: .dater {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.dater h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
}


.chevron-right img {
  float: right;

}

.chevron-left img {
 float: left;
}

Comment: @hidekinogo please update your answer with the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is you have the images contained within block level elements which occupy the full width of the browser viewport. Even then it won't work exactly as you wish but there are many ways to accomplish it.

First, you can put the images inside the `<h2>` to the left and right of the text. That's the easiest way.

Second, you can use the CSS pseudo classes [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

You can also set the width of the `<h2>` and float the everything, images included but the  must be set to `inline` to help this along.

There are more ways than just those.